# Почему при редактировании word из ASP.Net портится документ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть приложение на ASP.NET с формой для выбора значений из базы. При отправке формы эти поля и связные с ним заполняются в шаблон договора при помощи NPOI.

Опытным путём пришел к выводу, что документ портится при вставке в таблицу пустого значения вот на вот этом месте:

```
   XWPFTable t = doc.GetTable((CT_Tbl)o);
     foreach (XWPFTableRow row in t.Rows)
     {
         foreach (XWPFParagraph p in row.GetCell(1).Paragraphs)
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
             {
                 if (p.Text.IndexOf("#" + keys[k] + "#") > -1)
                 {
                     if (k == 0)
                         p.ReplaceText("#" + keys[k] + "#", podpisantOG);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Переписал немного код, чтобы при пустом значении поля метка заменялась на пробел (т.к. метку необходимо стереть в любом случае), но документ всё равно портится. Если значение есть - заменяется без проблем. Подскажите, почему так и можно ли как то просто стереть значение?

Вот так выглядит код сейчас:

```
 XWPFTable t = doc.GetTable((CT_Tbl)o);
 foreach (XWPFTableRow row in t.Rows)
 {
     foreach (XWPFParagraph p in row.GetCell(1).Paragraphs)
     {
         for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++)
         {
             if (p.Text.IndexOf("#" + keys[k] + "#") > -1)
             {
                 if (podpisantOG != "null")
                 {
                     if (k == 0)
                         p.ReplaceText("#" + keys[k] + "#", podpisantOG);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      if (k==0)
                          p.ReplaceText("#" + keys[k] + "#", " ");
                  }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка происходит, если пытаться отредактировать уже созданный файл.

Если прочитать файл в переменную, а потом создать новый файл куда записать отредактированный текст, ошибок не возникнет.